# Font Awesome Icon for section symbol (law)

Tags: fonts, icons, font-awesome, symbols

After searching for a long time: does anyone know the right font awesome icon for this symbol?

§

?!?

Answer (score 5):

The mark, known as "section sign", Unicode U+00A7, is not included in Font Awesome (as of this writing anyway). And it probably isn't really necessary, as it's included in the vast majority of "Latin" fonts (those supporting U.S. & Western Europe). You can get to it in HTML using `&sect;`, `&#167;` or `&#xa7;`

Answer (score 0):

The requested icon has been added to Font Awesome in version 6 in the January of 2021. After updating to that version it will be available with the name "section".